# How can I add a rule to eslint to check camelCase folder names?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, eslint

I tried the "ls-lint" library for this, but I want to find some kind of solution for eslint so that the errors are in real time.

Comment: Do you want to make camel case folder names mandatory or illegal?

Comment: realtime with which tool or IDE?  what is constantly checking all your files against the eslint config?

Comment: Yes, I want to make them mandatory. I work in vs code.

Comment: Do you want it to outlaw ones like this `foldername` or just ones like this `folder-name` `folder name`.  The first example is harder than just searching for spaces and hyphens in the path

Comment: I want to be given an error if the folder name is like this - "FolderName", "folder-name", "folder_name" etc... And so that everything is good in this case - "folderName"